# VBA Excel cmdLoad method

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using legacy code from another one, but it through out an error in cmdLoad:

```
Method or data member not found
```

Could you please let me know what is cmd.Load method in vba? is it user define or public attribute?
Thank you.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    With Me.cmdLoad
        .Left = 3
        .Top = 3
        .Height = 20
        .Width = 110
        .Font.Size = 8
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: no such method in vba. it seems a piece of code stolen from a userform code pane

Comment: `cmdLoad` is very likely a reference to a command button `Load`. If you don't have such a button on your worksheet this code will not work. Either create a button with that name or adjust the name to the actual name of your button's name.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ, you wanted to write _"a reference to a command button `cmdLoad`"_ didn't you?

Comment: @HTH No, actually I meant that the button is probably titeled `Load` or at least something similar. Doesn't make much sence to give a button the caption `Cancel` and name it `cmdLoad`. Usually people use some logic there. So a button with the title `Load` (or similar) is probably something the OP will easily find in the original project without checking all the control's names.

Comment: @Peh, I see. In any case that piece of code would actually work should an ActiveX button named "cmdLoad" be in place

Comment: @HTH yes, that is what I said. It will only work if there is a button named `cmdLoad`. Since it does not work, there is that button missing.